# Docker webpack doesn't create bundle in right place

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I am using Docker to run my React universal application using docker-compose as an control tool. Unfortunately, after webpack successfully creates the bundles my `pm2` inside docker can't find the script and my container exits with error.

What is the best way to debug this or solve the problem?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:erbium
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install pm2 -g
RUN npm install bower -g

COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install

COPY . /app/

RUN bower install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "start", "ecosystem.config.js", "--env", "production"]
```

**docker-compoe service**

```
client:
    container_name: client_folder
    image: client_image
    build: ./finstead-client
    volumes:
      - ./client_folder:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    restart: "always"
    ports:
      - "4000:8080"
```

the application is inside folder `client_folder` and I use volumes to attach my files to the docker container. But In my opinion it doesn't attach volumes after `buildtime` and on runtime it can't find the files.

I would appreciate a lot if you could give me advice or help me find out the root of the problem.

Comment: The `volumes:` will overwrite the code in the image with arbitrary content from the host, plus the anonymous volume for `node_modules` causes Docker to actively ignore changes in `package.json`.  Does deleting the `volumes:` help?  Does directly using `node` instead of pm2 work any better?  What's the actual error you get?

Comment: I don't get an error on docker, but `pm2` acting as my entrypoint can't find `script.js` which should be generated by webpack and supposedly being generated per webpacks process output

Comment: @DavidMaze should note that I have done steps from nodejs official page or I'm missing something here? https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/